# RefineryCMS - Import tumblr feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed, tumblr, refinerycms

I need to import all the posts from tumblr to refinerycms blog. How should I go about it?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know what you meant. I am making a website using refinerycms and have setup blog using refinerycms blog engine. I need to import a current blog (tumblr) to refinerycms blog engine. I have read about wordpress import gem which imports xml data. Is there a way like that for tumblr posts?

Comment: I mean that the SO community would be happy to help you, but unfortunately can not. Because you did not do anything by yourself. Therefore, society has no starting point to begin to help you.

Comment: Oh ok. I was just expecting a gem something which would have been easy to implement as I could setup a website easily using rails and refinerycms being a noob. Still Thanks for replying.

Comment: Did you get this working? if so, please share what you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FeedJira](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira) gem. The gem allows you to import an RSS feed. Watch this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing/) for more details.

```
Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse("http://www.foozzz.com/rss").entries.each do |entry|
  # update refinery blog here
  Refinery::Blogs::Post.create(:title => entry.title, ....)
end
```